# pandas to_dict - list of rows by key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "key": ["a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
    "var1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    "var2": ["x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y"],
})
```

i.e.

```
  key  var1 var2
0   a     1    x
1   b     2    y
2   b     3    x
3   c     4    y
4   c     5    x
5   c     6    y
```

I am trying to transform the data to generate a dict with unique `key` values as top level keys, and a list of records for the other columns (`var1` and `var2`)

Expected output:

```
{
    "a": [{"var1": 1, "var2": "x"}],
    "b": [{"var1": 2, "var2": "y"}, {"var1": 3, "var2": "x"}],
    "c": [{"var1": 4, "var2": "y"}, {"var1": 5, "var2": "x"}, {"var1": 6, "var2": "y"}],
}
```

I tried using the code below, which works, but uses a for loop which makes it slow for large dataframes. How can I achieve the expected result in a more idiomatic way with pandas?

```
result = {}
for key in df["key"].unique():
    key_df = df[df["key"] == key]
    result[key] = key_df.drop("key", axis=1).to_dict(orient="records")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`to_dict('records')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) in a dictionary comprehension:

```
out = {k: g.to_dict('records') for k, g in 
       df.set_index('key').groupby(level='key')}
```

Output:

```
{'a': [{'var1': 1, 'var2': 'x'}],
 'b': [{'var1': 2, 'var2': 'y'}, {'var1': 3, 'var2': 'x'}],
 'c': [{'var1': 4, 'var2': 'y'},
       {'var1': 5, 'var2': 'x'},
       {'var1': 6, 'var2': 'y'}]}
```